# Walls, fences and hedges

Tags: meaning, word-choice

There are several words for walls, fences and hedges and I can't get clear in my mind what's what.

First let me clarify the English meanings (at least as I think of them):

1. A hedge is a boundary to a garden, field or property made from plants/trees/shrubs.
2. A fence is a boundary to a garden, field or property typically made from wood or wire mesh.
3. A wall is a boundary to a garden, field or property made from brick/stone/concrete.
4. A wall is also a side of a building or of a room in a building.

With those definitions in mind could someone please classify the following words:
壁, 塀, 垣, 生垣, any other words that spring to mind.

I'm assuming that 生垣 unambiguously means 'hedge' given the  生 kanji implying life, but I'm very confused about the others.

Comment: Image search will give you some ideas. You might want to add 柵 and フェンス to that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, 壁 is used for rooms or buildings and 塀/垣 for boundaries.

- 垣 is usually made of something 'natural'.
- 塀 is more wall-like (typically, top two in the first picture below or the second pic called ブロック塀{べい} - [source 1](https://mizushimanoie.jp/staff_blog/22772/), [source 2](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/tameikiman22/e/f778d083ff2560ff93e8b30e87413279)).

[垣根](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%9E%A3%E6%A0%B9/#jn-38295) in modern speech is synonymous with 垣, which has subtypes 生垣, 竹垣 etc. A typical 生垣 is as the bottom right one below, and 竹垣 is the bottom left. I think 生垣 is more or less a patch of shrubs. This can be a boundary between a property and outside, or between a path and fields in a park, for example.

[image]

[image]

---

柵/フェンス is typically like below (often seen in schools; [source](http://works.nogisuzu.main.jp/?eid=107)). A wire mesh fence would be called フェンス or 柵, but wood fence may be called 垣(根) as well.

[image]

---

Lastly, walls like [Hadrian's Wall](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%89%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8C%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E9%95%B7%E5%9F%8E) is called 長城. The (English) name should sound odd to most Japanese (at least to me), because it is too short (vertically) for 壁 (*the* translation for *wall*).

An aside: as above suggests, 塀 is usually shorter than 壁, but the wall surrounding a prison is still a 塀. As such 塀の中 is a euphemism for *in(side of) jail*.